# Ambiguous name detected: Worksheet_change

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to add a second code to a single worksheet and keep getting the "Ambiguous name detected" error. Realise that I need to combine the two codes but having trouble doing so. here are the two codes, one below the other:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


        'are changes made within answer range?

    Set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("Answers"))

    If Not (isect Is Nothing) Then

        For Each chng In Target.Cells

            'Get row number

            startY = Impact.Range("Answers").Row
            targetY = chng.Row
            row_offset = (targetY - startY) + 1

            rating_type = Impact.Range("Impacts").Cells(row_offset, 1)

            If rating_type = "Major / V.High" Then cols = 16711884
            If rating_type = "Significant / High" Then cols = 255
            If rating_type = "Important / Moderate" Then cols = 49407
            If rating_type = "Minor / Low" Then cols = 5287936
            If rating_type = "" Then cols = 16777215

            Impact.Range("Ratings").Cells(row_offset, 1).Interior.Color = cols
            Impact.Range("Impacts").Cells(row_offset, 1).Interior.Color = cols

        Next chng

    End If

End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' To Select Multiple Items from a Drop Down List in Excel
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Was hoping someone knows how to combine the two in order to circumvent this error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot have two separate change event code on the sheet module. If you have to track changes in more than one ranges, you can join the conditions in one change event code within the IF and ElseIf block. As the error Ambiguous Name is self explanatory i.e. you have two macros with the same names.

Comment: You have two procedures with the same name. It does not even matter at that point that this name is reserved for the event handler. You cannot have two procedures with the same name in one code module. If you now need to do more things on a worksheet change, copy the new code into the existing `Worksheet_Change` handler. Only you know how it should combine with the code that is already there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment, you can track changes in more than one range as shown in the below sample code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Exit the sub if more than one cells are changed at the same time
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

'Disable the event so that if the code changes the cell content of any cell, the code is not triggered again
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Error handling to skip the code if an error occurs during the code execution and enable the events again
On Error GoTo ErrorHandling

'Change event code will be triggered if any cell in column A is changed
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The content of a cell in colunm A has been changed."

'Change event code will be triggered if any cell in column C is changed
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The content of a cell in colunm C has been changed."

'Change event code will be triggered if any cell in column E is changed
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:E")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The content of a cell in colunm E has been changed."
End If

ErrorHandling:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```